# C# Populate ReportViewer from arrays (High Level)

Tags: c#, reportviewer

I'm going to build a few arrays and want to populate a rdlc report from them, but want to make sure I've got the high level process down before I start coding. I'm populating these arrays from calculations based on foxpro (sigh...) tables.

Do I need to create the report first through the wizard and throw generic columns in there, then adjust as necessary? Or can the code completely do everything? Previously, when I tried to do this through code-only, the Report.Refresh() wouldn't actually launch the report...

So:

1. Create Report with generic columns and modify as necessary later
2. Populate arrays
3. Stuff arrays into report and display?

Remember, I'm looking for a high-level process flow right now, there are tons of code examples on each individual element I'm just not sure I've got the process right.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research and fumbling around, I finally got it to work on my own...so if anyone else stumbles across this, here is what worked for me. I'm certain there are better ways to do this.

1. Populate Arrays as necessary
2. Create Data Set with a data table as defined
3. Populate dataset.datatable with arrays
4. Create report.rdlc using datatable from step 3
5. If using WPF, add the WinForms control to your WPF application
6. Stuff datatable in to datasource (reportdatasource.value = dataset.datatable)
7. Give reportviewer the embedded resource of your report
8. Refresh
9. ????
10. Profit!